# How to use getElementBy in Cognos11 to get the Value of a textelement?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, cognos-11

Heiho:-)##
I got some *text elements/singletons* in a *Cognos 11-report* to show some calculated values.
I added some *JavaScript* with *d3.js* to visualize those values.

I tried to get the value from a text element with *document.getElementsByClassName()*.
It works in a HTML-editor, but it doesn't when I try it in my *JavaScript* within *Cognos*.
I just get *"undefined"* in my alert message.
My text element in *Cognos* has the class called *"fname"*.
The rest of the script works and shows a chart when I use a hard coded value within the script.

**HTML-editor**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input class="fname" type="text" value="Michael">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("fname")[0].value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript for Cognos**

```
define(["http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"], function (d3) {
"use strict";

function D3Chart()
{
};

D3Chart.prototype.draw = function( oControlHost )
{
    var fname = document.getElementsByClassName("fname")[0].value;
    window.alert(fname);
    //some code
};

D3Chart.prototype.setData = function( oControlHost, oDataStore)
{
};

return D3Chart;
});
```